# Representations and Cartan decompositions of $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$

Tags: lie-algebras

It is well known that the Lie algebra of $SO(4,1)$ is given by the expression
$$A^tB+BA=0,\quad (\ast)$$
where $B=\text{diag}(1,1,1,1,-1)$, that is,
$$\mathfrak{so}(4,1)=\{A\in\text{Mat}(5,\mathbb{C}):A^tB+BA=0\}.$$
Take an element $A\in\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ and write it as
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} W & x \\ y^t & z \end{pmatrix},$$
where $W\in\text{Mat}(4,\mathbb{C})$, $x,y\in\mathbb{C}^2$, $z\in\mathbb{C}$. In this block decomposition,
$B = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{I}_4 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$
and $(\ast)$ becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix} W^t & y \\ x^t & z\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{I}_4 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{I}_4 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} W & x \\ y^t & z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Writing out separately the equation for each block we get the conditions
$$W^t = -W, \qquad y = x, \qquad z = 0,$$
so,
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{so}(4,1)
&= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} W & x \\ x^t & 0\end{pmatrix} : W^t = -W \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -w_1 & -w_2 & -w_3 & x_1 \\ w_1 & 0 & -w_4 & -w_5 & x_2 \\ w_2 & w_4 & 0 & -w_6 & x_3 \\ w_3 & w_5 & w_6 & 0 & x_4 \\ x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}.
\end{align}
It is also well known that every $A\in\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ can be written uniquely as
$$\begin{pmatrix} W & x \\ x^t & 0\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} W & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ x^t & 0\end{pmatrix},$$
which is the Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)=\mathfrak{l}\oplus\mathfrak{p}$.

---

Now, I also have seen that $SO(4,1)$ can be realized as
$$SO(4,1)=\{A\in\text{Mat}(5,\mathbb{C}):A^tBA=B, \det(A)=1\},$$ where $$B=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1,1),$$
(an even with some other stranger matrices like $B=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$).
Using the same idea as before, and writting now the element $A\in\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ as $A = \begin{pmatrix} z & x^t \\ y & W \end{pmatrix}$, one can get the following representation by blocks for $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$:
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{so}(4,1)
&=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x^t \\ x & W\end{pmatrix} : W^t = -W \right\} \\
&=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\ x_1 & 0 & -w_1 & -w_2 & -w_3 \\ x_2 & w_1 & 0 & -w_4 & -w_5 \\ x_3 & w_2 & w_4 & 0 & -w_6 \\ x_4 & w_3 & w_5 & w_6 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}.
\end{align}
With this representation it is claimed in a paper that the Cartan decomposition $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)=\mathfrak{l}\oplus\mathfrak{p}$ is given by
$$\mathfrak{l}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} A_1 & 0 \\ 0 & A_2\end{pmatrix} : A_1^tI_{1,1}+I_{1,1}A_1 = 0, A_2+A_2^t = 0 \right\},$$
and
$$\mathfrak{p}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & B_1 \\ -B_1^tI_{1,1} & 0\end{pmatrix}\right\},$$
where $I_{1,1}=\text{diag}(-1,1)$.

---

**My questions**

1. I checked the conditions for the following blocks $A_1, A_2$ and $B_1$ and they hold, are these the right blocks for the decomposition?

$A_1=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x_1 \\ x_1 & 0\end{pmatrix},\quad$ $A_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -w_4 & -w_5 \\ w_4 & 0 & -w_6 \\ w_5 & w_6 & 0 \end{pmatrix},\quad$ $B_1=\begin{pmatrix} x_2 & x_3 & x_4 \\ -w_1 & -w_2 & -w_3 \end{pmatrix}$.

2. Now, if all the previous is correct and I am given with a matrix for which I want to know whether it belongs to $\mathfrak{l}$ or $\mathfrak{p}$, how should I proceed? Since there seems to be different representations for the Lie algebra and also for the Cartan decomposition, how can I know if a given matrix belongs to any of these subspaces of $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cartan decomposition is not unique, but only unique up to conjugacy. In the case of $\mathfrak g:=\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ you can describe it in a way which is independent of the relazation is follows. Your algebra by definition is the algebra of all endomorphisms of a five-dimensional space $V$ endowed with a Lorentzian inner product. The main input for the Cartan decomposition is given by choosing a subspace $W\subset V$ of dimension $4$ on which the Lorentzian inner product is positive definite. Then the stabilizer of $W$ in $\mathfrak g$ is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(4)\times\mathfrak{so}(1)=\mathfrak{so}(4)$ and this is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak k$ of a maxiaml compact subgroup. Via the restriciton of the adjoint action $\mathfrak k$ acts on $\mathfrak g$ leaving the subspace $\mathfrak k$ invariant. By general results, it follows that there is a $\mathfrak k$-invariant complementary subspace $\mathfrak p\subset\mathfrak g$ to that invariant subspace (which in this situation is uniquely determined). The Cartan decomposition then is $\mathfrak g=\mathfrak k\oplus\mathfrak p$.

In particular, the blocks $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B_1$ has the wrong sizes, you need $B_1$ to be a $2\times 2$-block. (The decomposition you describe also points out - via the two $A$-blocks - the fact that $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ is not simple but only semisimple which is specific to dimension $4$.) But the matrices $A_1$ and $A_2$ do not form blocks in the strict sense of the word.

So the question whether a given matrix lies in $\mathfrak k$ or in $\mathfrak p$ strictly speaking does not make sense unless you fix one Cartan decomposition. Also then "most" matrices do not lie in either of the two factors. A reasonable related notion may be to look at the trace of $A^2$ (which always is negative on $\mathfrak k$ and positive on $\mathfrak p$).

Comment: Is the notion of the trace of $A^2$ independent of the choice of the Cartan decomposition?

Comment: I am sorry, maybe my formulation was a bit misleading. What I meant is that whenever you have a realization of $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$, then you can look at matrices in there and take the trace of the square of such a matrix. (By general results, this coincides up to a non-zero multiple with the Killing form on the algebra.) This defines a quadratic form on $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ and for any choice of Cartan decomposition, this quadratic form is negative definite on $\mathfrak k$ and positive definite on $\mathfrak p$. (This comes from the basic definition of Cartan involutions.)

Comment: Could you explain why the blocks $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B_1$ are wrong? By the representation of $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ that I get using the matrix $B=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1,1)$ (the one that the authors use in this paper) are the only blocks that make sense to me...

Comment: The $\mathfrak p$-component in the Cartan decomposition has to be of dimension $4$, whereas the $\mathfrak k$-component has to be isomorphic to $\mathfrak{so}(4)\cong\mathfrak{su}(2)\times\mathfrak{su}(2)$. For the diagonal matrix $B$, the Cartan decomposition is again given by $W$ and $x$ as indicated in your question. For the other choice of $B$ the decomposition is more complicated, since basically this realizes $\mathfrak{so}(4,1)$ as $\mathfrak{so}(1,1)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(3)$ with second summand corresponding to the central block, and the Cartan decomposition is not given by blocks.

Comment: Ok, so then for the matrix $B=\text{diag}(-1,1,1,1,1)$ the Cartan decomposition is given by $\mathfrak{l}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & W \end{pmatrix} : W^t=-W \right\}$ and $\mathfrak{p}=\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ x^t & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}$, is it? But then, neither the block $B_1$ is two by two as you said in the answer nor is a matrix that can be multiplied by $I_{1,1}$... because is just the vector $x$.

Comment: Yes, that's the right decomposition.I did not understand originally that the claim about the blocks refers to the diagonal $B$. With the suggested blocks, things cannot work out dimension-wise. If $A_1$ can be multiplied by $I_{1,1}$ it must be of size $2$, but then the space of $A_1$'s is one-dimensional. Likewise the $A_2$ block can only contribute 3 more dimensions, but $\mathfrak k$ has to have dimension 6. Your analysis of the block sizes looks reasonable, so there has to be an error elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer and the comments, really appreciate it. I'll have a look at it again in a few days and see if I find the mistake(s). In case you're curious, the paper I mentioned is this: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3953 The relevant part about Lie algebras is in sections 2.2 and 2.3, from page 8 to 11.

Comment: The paper you refer to deals with a symmetric decomposition $\mathfrak{so}(1,4)=\mathfrak k\oplus\mathfrak p$ with $\mathfrak k=\mathfrak{so}(1,1)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(3)$ and $\mathfrak p$ of dimension $6$. This exactly corresponds to the block decomposition you have indicated (with $B$ providing $6$ dimensions), and everything is fine. The name "Cartan decomposition" usually is reserved for the case that $\mathfrak k$ is a maximal compact subalgebra (which is also very important from the point of view of symmetric spaces). So it is a problem of wording only.